the get_file() function freezes my script
When the tf.keras.utils.get_file line is done with downloading or if the file is already there, my script just freezes like using sleep() but infinitely. I'm pretty new to tensorflow and python, so I have no idea why this would happen.
I am using tensorflow 2.16.1 and python 3.12.4 if that helps.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import re
import shutil
import string
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras import losses # type: ignore

url = "https://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz"

dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file("aclImdb_v1", url,
                                    untar=True, cache_dir='.',
                                    cache_subdir='')

print("test")

dataset_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset), 'aclImdb')

os.listdir(dataset_dir)

train_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'train')
os.listdir(train_dir)

sample_file = os.path.join(train_dir, 'pos/1181_9.txt')
with open(sample_file) as f:
  print(f.read())




in the line assigning the value of dataset, you list the file name as "aclImdb_v1". However, in the line where you assign dataset_dir, you have 'aclImdb'. Could this change in given file name be causing the problem?

@FrasherGray it sadly didnt work but still thanks

I have realized that nothing in this code is wrong it just takes a very long time to extract all the files from the tar file that the get_file() function downloads. But i still thank you guys for trying to help.

If you are using cachedir = '.', that may be part of your problem, since that is the cache to which you are saving the downloaded file. A more normal cachedir would be $KERAS_HOME or ~/.keras/. Also, untar is deprecated - please see
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file
